# Typeorm: how to declare a specific entity as a variable (with a relation)

Tags: typescript, types, typeorm, relation

My Call Entity relation:

```
  @OneToMany(
    () => Comment, (comment) => comment.call,
    { eager: true })
  comments?: Comment[];
```

My Comment Entity relation:

```
  @ManyToOne(() => Call, (call) => call.comments)
  @JoinColumn()
  call: Call;
```

If I try to declare a call as a Call entity type and I have this following error:

```
Property 'call' is missing in type '{ id: number; message: string; commented_at: Date; callId: number; }' but required in type 'Comment'
```

```
    const call: Call = {
        id: 1, 
        name: 'test', 
        date: new Date, 
        duration: 120, 
        crmActivityId: '12', 
        comments: [{
            id: 1,
            message: 'Made by Aircall',
            commented_at: new Date,
            callId: 1,
            call:
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        }]};
```

I have to add a call relation in my comments array but it is not possible.

How can I fix this error, do I have to add a specific decorator to my relations ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add name in join column :

@JoinColumn({
name: 'callId'
})

call: Call;

Comment: The problem is still persisting

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution

```
        const call: Call = {
            id: 1, 
            name: 'test', 
            date: new Date, 
            duration: 120, 
            crmActivityId: '12'
        };

        const item = new Call();

        item.comments = [
            {
                id: 1,
                message: 'Good answer!',
                commented_at: new Date,
                callId: 1,
                call: call,
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                message: 'Made by Aircall',
                commented_at: new Date,
                callId: 1,
                call: call,
            }
        ];
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).